# Android navigation architecture component - system's back button exits the app

Tags: android, navigation

I am making a demo using android's **navigation architecture component**. I have an `activity` and two `fragments`.

In the activity's xml, I have added the following code-

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/match_constraints"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/match_constraints"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

And then I have set the first fragment as the start destination. In the first fragment, on a button's click I have done following -

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment)
```

And it works fine. Now when I press system's back button, ideally I should go back to first fragment, but the app exits. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863846/how-to-handle-back-button-to-go-to-specific-fragment

Comment: @Benjamin this answer does not use the latest navigation architecture component.

Comment: @HimanshuGanoliya please post your activity code and navigation graph xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose, this is occurring in your code just because you might be handling the `onBackPressed()` functionality somewhere in your `BaseActivity`. Please look carefully.

I hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /** orrerride activity onBackPressed() **/

private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        int start = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).getCurrentDestination().getId();
        if (start == R.id.nav_home) {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }
            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press back again to exits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                }
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is not about implementing the press-back-again-to-exit functionality. It asks why clicking the back button in a non-top-level fragment exits the app and how to fix that.